# Icon disappears in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I'm programming a website where I created 4 buttons that link to my social media profiles. I want to include the icon of the resp. social media on the button. I use the Mono Social Icons Font.

On this website you see what it should look like: http://cholleton.ch

This is the code I used:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  <a href="https://be.linkedin.com/pub/thomas-geusens/6/630/809" class="symbol linkedin"></a>
</div>
```

In main.css I added

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Mono Social Icons Font';
src: url('../fonts/social/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.eot');
src: url('../fonts/social/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/social/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/social/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/social/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.svg#MonoSocialIconsFont') format('svg');
src: url('../fonts/social/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

.symbol, a.symbol:before {
font-family: 'Mono Social Icons Font';
-webkit-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
-moz-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
-ms-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
-o-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-ms-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.links {
font-size: 10vh;
text-align: center;
}

.linkedin {
background-color: #4488cc;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Thomas

Comment: hi Rachel, no, that's just an example from another website...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just forgot to put the text in your link, like this :

```
<a href="https://be.linkedin.com/pub/thomas-geusens/6/630/809" class="symbol linkedin">circlelinkedin</a>
```

**See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsm3nzkk/)**

Comment: Thanks Tom; but if I enter text it just shows that text. How can I make sure it shows an icon?

Comment: So I suppose the font not correctly loaded. Check the Chrome or Firefox Inspector to see if you have 404 errors.

Comment: I created this Fiddle to show you how to procede : https://jsfiddle.net/Lsm3nzkk/

Answer (score 0):

if you have the image set as a background image in your class then out a non-breaking space `&nbsp;` before your end `</a>` tag. If you want an image that is saved on your directory then use something like this

```
 <img src="http://www.yourdomain.com/images/linkedin.jpg" alt="linked in">
```